# Discrimination Free Git Platform

Tags: collaboration

Github, a plataform for collaborating on code implementation has blocked Iranian's based on the fact that they are from Iran. The excuse is that the blockage is to comply with US trade laws.

Now my Iranian students cannot access their work.

Does there exist an european version of github, which is preferentially likely not to adopt the same kind of ridiculous restrictions?

Comment: Could you explain why this restriction is ridiculous? You either follow the laws (which themselves might be bad laws, but that is not the point) or you get into trouble. A European site that wants to have clients in the US will face similar trouble, a site that doesn't care about laws might not be the best place to host stuff...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that did not keep a local backup of their work in the cloud?

Comment: If you rephrase your question in the direction what you could do to help your students continue their work, you would avoid the "shopping" problem and maybe get the question re-opened.

Comment: @Dirk: The fact that GitHub says they are required to do this to follow trade laws does not necessarily mean that this is true (i.e., that the law requires this of them).  Companies often make dubious assertions of restrictions they are under as a means of justifying their own business choices.

Comment: Assuming that the institution is not located in Iran, the students should be able to use the school server as a proxy to access github (or use any other proxy).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs No --- it's impossible to work using git and not have a local copy of the whole repo. They may have lost bug tracking tickets (if they were using them), but not the source code.

Comment: @Erwan No, they can't. As you can read [here](https://github.com/1995parham/github-do-not-ban-us), *GitHub decided to [...] ban every user that used Iran's IP address somewhere their history no matter where she/he is living, while they could just restrict access by IP address like other US-based companies. This action is kind of ban by nationality.*

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for the link. If that's true it's a blanket ban which discriminates against anybody who ever traveled to Iran, including when it was legal to do so and including non-nationals. Looks like a good recipe for being sued imho.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That's what I meant. I know that git has a local copy of the history, but the meta-information needs to be locally stored, too.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that you best bet would be to have your university host a server running [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/), [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/), [gogs](https://gogs.io/), or something similar. It would take a bit of money and technical know-how to run the server, but at least you would be safe from embargos.